# Proving perpendicularity in an acute triangle

Tags: geometry

In an acute-angled triangle ABC, let us denote H as its orthocenter and I as its incenter. Let D be the perpendicular projection of I on the line BC, and E be the image of point A in symmetry with center I. Furthermore, F is the perpendicular projection of the point H on the line ED. Prove that the points B, H, F, C lie on a circle.

I think the idea here is the circumcircle BHC is the reflection of circumcircle ABC respect to BC. But I don't know how to proceed, can anybody help?

Comment: Extend $AH$ to touch the circumcircle at $J$. Note that $\angle HCA=90-\angle B=\angle JAB=\angle JCB$, where the last equation is because both angles are inscribed on the same arc of the circumcircle. Since $HJ$ is perpendicular to $BC$, then $J$ is the reflection of $H$ with respect to $BC$.

Comment: Okay thank you for the hint